# Why does WP-admin password change automatically after 2-3 hours in Live domain?

Tags: wordpress, cloud, hosting, servr

Wordpress Stage website working fine but Live website will change password automatically.

Hi EveryBody.
How are you.? I am facing some problems.
Problems:  My client's WordPress website. We have developed with Stage website. working fine but when shifted to the live domain.
WP-admin password changed automatically after 2 to 3 hours. I don't know why.?
Please guide me. If you have any ideas. about my problems.
Regards

Comment: Q: Where are you hosting this WP site?